# Inequality plot like Wolfram Alpha

Tags: plotting, inequalities

I'd like to reproduce in Mathematica the output of [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%204%28x-1%29%5E2%2F%289%28x%2B2%29%5E2%29%20%3C%3D%201%2F100) Wolfram Alpha query. Of course I can just use `WolframAlpha` but I'd like to manipulate the graphics (add another function, add legends, etc.) so I'm looking for a 'native' function.

I know about `RegionPlot` but I don't understand how to use it for this kind of inequality (if I just put it as first argument, it outputs a rectangular plot, which makes sense). Moreover I'd like to keep the graphs of the functions in the plot.

Comment: Use the `Filling` option of `Plot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Filling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html).

```
Plot[{Sin[x], 1/x}, {x, 0, 4}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {None, Automatic}}}]
```

[image]